# A function to operate with the rows we want

Tags: r, correlation

I want to select only two of the multiple rows in the dataset and perform a correlation test. How can I choose the two I want among multiple lines and do it without getting an error from the correlation test?

normally I can test correlation between values in two columns in a dataset. I tried this. but i don't know how to do correlation test between rows i choose

Comment: `mydf[c(insert_row_numbers_here), ]` will return the rows you selected of a data frame. For example `iris[c(1, 4:6, 19), ]`